# Netbeans - "The <CATALINA_HOME>/conf/server.xml can't be read"

Tags: java, netbeans, ubuntu, tomcat

Estoy tratando de levantar un servidor Tomcat en Netbeans, ya he instalado el plugin para Tomcat y he configurado correctamente mi variable de entorno `CATALINA_HOME` pero me bota este error:

> The /conf/server.xml can't be read

No se que pueda estar pasando, al hacer `echo $CATALINA_HOME`obtengo `usr/share/tomcat`. Mi archivo `server.xml`si existe en la ruta `usr/share/tomcat/conf/server.xml`

Estoy trabajando con Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Has revisado los permisos del archivo?

Comment: Sí, era eso, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal vez deberías revisar los permisos del archivo, ejecuta este comando en `usr/share/tomcat/conf/` para poder ver los permisos de los archivos, ahi revisa los permisos de `server.xml`

```
ls -l
```

Si fuera el caso que no tengas todos los permisos suficientes ejecuta esto:

```
chmod 777 server.xml
```

Comment: Sí, era eso, ¡gracias!

Comment: Permisos 777 estás loco ! Cambia ese tipo de permiso

Comment: @JackNavaRow que permisos deberia usar el OP para ese archivo, como podrias mejorar la respuesta?

Comment: primero. por seguridad se debe crear un usuario tomcat que tenga solo el acceso a esa carpeta unica , que el grupo y el usuario tengan acesso , debe de darle permisos a 600, 640 o 660 (dependiendo de qué acceso) el grupo de tomcat necesita, para las dudas [mira que significan los permisos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518259/understanding-chmod-symbolic-notation-and-use-of-octal.)

Comment: incluso cambiando el dueño con un chown  con los permisos mencionados y que solo el usuario tomcat acceda